# Seg fault on free call

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, free

```
char* meminfo()
{
char* buffer = NULL;
FILE* fp = fopen("/proc/meminfo", "r");
ssize_t read;

char* json = malloc(4096);
char* original = json;
json[0] = '\0';
json = strcat(json, "{");

size_t value = 1024;

while ( (read = getline(&buffer, &value, fp)) != -1)
{
    char name[1024];
    name[0] = '\0';

    char val[1024];
    val[0] = '\0';

    sscanf(buffer, "%s:", name);
    buffer = buffer + strlen(name);
    name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';

    sscanf(buffer, "%s kB", val);

    json = strcat(json, "\"");
    json = strcat(json, name);
    json = strcat(json, "\": \"");
    json = strcat(json, val);
    json = strcat(json, "\", ");
}
int n = strlen(json);
json[n - 2] = '}';
json[n - 1] = '\0';

fclose(fp);
return original;
}
```

So I have this function that reads and generates a json string object for the data in the meminfo file. However, if I call free() on the return value of this function, I get a seg fault and I can't figure it out (I malloc the variable within the function and free it after). Any ideas?

Comment: Then, char* json; should be global

Comment: weird, in my case(CentOS 5.3, gcc 4.3) your code with free() works well. no seg. fault. anyway. why don't you initialize `json` with memset() or bzero()?

Comment: You probably overflowed the 4096 buffer size.  You should program defensively and ensure you don't write more than the buffer can hold.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes. I agree with you. dynamically allocation (e.g firstly figure out file size) is better. but I think 4Kb is enough for  `/proc/meminfo`

Comment: Using a difference on indexing an array in general is a dangerous construct, which should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifing where `buffer` points to between the successive call to `getline()`.

```
buffer = buffer + strlen(name);
```

As memory pointed to by `buffer` might be reallocated by `getline()` during each coming iteration it shall not be modified in between.

To fix this make a backup like shown below:

```
char* meminfo()
{ 
    char * buffer = NULL;

    ...

    size_t value = 0;

    while ( (read = getline(&buffer, &value, fp)) != -1)
    {
      char * p = buffer; /* save the address, as buffer is modfied below. */

      ...

      buffer = p; /*restore address. */
    }
```

---

Also the code misses error checking on system calls.

---

Another issue is that this lines fails miserably in case `getline()` does not return anything:

```
size_t n = strlen(json); 
/* json is "{" so its length would be 1 ... */

json[n - 2] = '}'; 
/* ... so here the code would address json[-1]. Which provokes undefinded behaviour. */
```